# MySQL: производительность сервера базы данных при одном большом емком запросе

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то снизить нагрузку на базу данных при выполнении одного большого запроса?

Например, пользователи работают с таблицей, где определенные поля проиндексированы и всё вроде бы хорошо.

Но есть большой запрос, который выполняется по крону раз в 10 минут.

Может ли этот запрос, как то тормознуть пользовательские запросы?

Мне представляется, что каждый запрос как бы стоит в очереди на выполнение, пока другой не выполнится.

Или в MySQL есть многопоточность, которая делит все запросы на определенные подпроцессы, у каждого продпроцесса свой ресурс, который практически не может превысить установленные значения?

В любом случае, можно ли сделать как-нибудь так, чтобы этот большой емкий запрос выполнялся медленно, чтобы не занимал все ресурсы сервера БД?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL-сервер написан как многопоточное приложение, но это не гарантирует, что при выполнении сложного запроса он никак не будет влиять на соседние. При его выполнении более чем может забиться табличный кэш или серьезно повысится нагрузка на процессор (в зависимости от системы и настроек в my.cnf).

По поводу приоритетов, есть в настройках параметр low-priority-updates, он может понизить приоритет операций INSERT/UPDATE, отдавая предпочтения операциям чтения (SELECT).

Что представляет собой ваш большой запрос? Это операции чтения или записи? Большие запросы вставки/обновления желательно разбивать на несколько частей, иначе MySQL их может просто не проглотить (ограничение по длине запроса). Если там сложный SELECT, то его желательно также оптимизировать через денормализацию данных и затачивание индексов под этот конкретный запрос.

P.S. В любом случае рекомендую провести практический эксперимент с созданием усиленной нагрузки на базу, чтобы уже наверняка посмотреть как поведет себя сервер.

Comment: Например, сложный запрос на обновление таблицы с подзапросом SELECT. Таким образом, это неконтроллируемый администратором процесс?

Comment: @Pavel лучше такие запросы сразу разбивать на простые части (может помочь денормализация). особенно когда станет задача масштабирования системы, то JOIN'ы станет достаточно проблематично использовать (уменьшится связанность данных, когда отдельные таблицы хранятся на разных серверах). на практике намного удобнее сделать дублирование нескольких колонок в разных таблицах, чем делать сложные, грузящие систему запросы.